# Ember js - correct syntax in template when sorting and filtering through each loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an each loop which outputs a table of data. Each row includes created_date, title, publisher and category. In order to use sortProperties in the relevant controller (To sort the posts by created_date), I have set it to loop over the controller:

```html
<button {{action 'reverseOrder' 'created_date'}}>Reverse Date Order</button>
{{#each controller as |post|}} 
  ...
{{/each}}
```

I would also like to have buttons which filter this list by other columns (For example publisher). I've looked at [this jsbin example](http://blessanmathew.com/2014/08/16/ember.js-list-filtering-using-a-multiple-selection-filter-component.html), which passes filteredContent to the each helper in the template, and then uses that in the controller to do the filtering:

```html
{{#each filteredContent}}
...
{{/each}}
```

```js
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({

  filteredContent: [],

  actions: {
    filterByPublisher: function(filterFn) {
      this.set('filteredContent', this.get('model').filter(filterFn));
    }
  }
});
```

What is the correct way to pass filteredContent to the each helper which already specifies the controller?

I've tried various things-

```html
{{#each controller as |post| filteredContent}}
{{#each filteredContent controller as |post|}}
```

However I get errors like the following:

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: If you pass more than one argument to the each helper, it must be in the form {{#each foo in bar}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass two arguments to `{{#each}}`. The `{{#each}}` helper only accepts one argument which is an array to be iterated over.

Create a computed property that would return an array of data sorted and filtered according to all the options.

Example:

```
  // Item format: {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 5}

  result: Ember.computed(
    'model.@each.foo',
    'model.@each.bar',
    'model.@each.baz',
    'sortColumn',
    'sortAsc',
    'filterMinFoo',
    'filterMinBar',
    'filterMinBaz',    
    function() {
      var filterMinFoo = this.get('filterMinFoo');
      var filterMinBar = this.get('filterMinBar');
      var filterMinBaz = this.get('filterMinBaz');

      var result = this
        .get('model')
        .filter(function(item) {
          return item.get('foo') >= filterMinFoo &&
            item.get('bar') >= filterMinBar &&
            item.get('baz') >= filterMinBaz;
        })
        .sortBy(this.get('sortColumn'));

      return this.get('sortAsc') ? result : result.reverse();
    }
  )
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kegavo/1/edit?html,js,output